# Why does my database lose recent data ? Django application deployed on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have deployed a Django web application on Heroku and it has the data I have added in the development phase, still when I add new data, the website holds the data temporarily for some time ( I don't know how long ), and then the website resets to the state in which it was first deployed. I don't understand why this is happening and would appreciate the help.

As I said if you make changes ( you have to register first ) they will hold and be stored for some unknown time to me and after that time they will disappear.
Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: TL;DR: don't use SQLite on Heroku.

Comment: FYI there should not be any requirement for someone to visit your site, to help you with a programming question. Please refrain from linking to your site. Also, links like this change or disappear over time, so this question might have a broken link at some point. If you want someone to help, please edit your question to include all needed details.

Comment: @DavidMakogon There is absolutely no need to visit the site , I just added it in case someone wanted to try it out for themselves , I removed the link , thanks for the heads up